# convert date string to ISO date with timezone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime

I have a collection of dates and times, it is formatted like this:

`01.07.2013 16:10`.

I know I have to rearrange to match ISO standard, so I managed to end up with a string like this:

`2013-07-01T16:10`.

From this, I need to create a `Date` Object. After reading many questions on here about this I am a little confused about how to add a timezone to this. All of the times are in New York Cities local time, which I also want to store the dates in.

So since Javascript takes the timezone from my machine, I changed it to be the one from NYC. However, the following part confuses me the most:

```
> print(new Date("2013-07-01T16:10"))
Mon Jul 01 2013 16:10:00 GMT+2000 (EDT)
```

Question: Why does it say GMT+2000 when my local time is GMT-0400 (the one of NYC)? Is this 'correct'? If not, how is this done properly?

--Updates:
I am using mongoDB `3.4.4` and interpreter Version is `MozJS-38`. The `systemsetup -gettimezone` returns `America/New_York`. Running mongo-express in chrome shows: `Mon Jul 01 2013 06:00:00 GMT+0200 (EDT)` for `ISODate("2013-07-01T04:00:00.000Z")` stored, but the shell says `Tue Jul 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+2000 (EDT)` for `print(new Date("2013-07-01T04:00:00.000Z"));`.

Comment: Are you sure it says exactly `"GMT+2000"`?  If so, your machine's time zone data is corrupted.  There is no where in the world that is 20 hours ahead of GMT.  Also, New York would be `"GMT-0400"` in that format.  Are you sure you aren't typoing the zeros here?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Yes I also expected it to be `"GMT-0400"`. I am using MacOS, did not restart after changing the timezone. Maybe this is the cause.

Comment: Ok, but you *wrote* `"GMT-4000"`, so you had the zero in the wrong position.  Are you sure you didn't do the same with `"GMT+2000"`?  Did you mean `"GMT+0200"`?

Comment: You don't need to restart your computer, but you should restart your browser.  What browser are you using?  What specific entry is your time zone set to in MacOS? (use `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` from the terminal to check)

Comment: Also, `print` launches the print-preview dialog in most browsers, and isn't defined in Node.  What environment are you in that `print` is valid?  One would usually `console.log`.

Comment: Using Chrome. That print is copied out of a mongo terminal. I do understand now that printing a UTC date will print it in the machines timezone, so changing it will change the print outcome. No matter why it says GMT+2000, saving it as UTC as Rodrigo pointed it out below is the way I think I will store the data.

Comment: Oh, you didn't tell us you were using MongoDB.  That makes all the difference.  What version of MongoDB are you using?  What values do you get for `version()` and `interpreterVersion()` on the shell?  read my comments in Rodrigo's answer about changes in ECMAScript, you are likely affected by that if you are not on a more recent version of MongoDB.

Comment: And again, what do you get with `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone`?  Also, what do you get with `printenv TZ` (if anything)?  GMT+2000 is not applicable anywhere in the world, so something screwy is going on.  Do you see that same output from *both* Chrome and MongoDB?

Comment: @MattJohnson I updated my question with these infos. Where should `printenv TZ` be executed?

Comment: At the os terminal.  But honestly, I think this is a Mongo bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145583/discussion-between-ffritz-and-matt-johnson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the time zone offset when creating the `Date` object.

```
> new Date("2013-07-01T16:10-04:00")
2013-07-01T20:10:00.000Z
```

Comment: If the local time zone is actually in that offset, then there's no need to specify it.  An ISO date+time without offset shall be interpreted as local time, by ISO8601 and ES2015+ (all modern browsers).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. My mistake.

Comment: It changed in ES6 to match ISO8601.  ES 5.1 and lower would interpret as UTC.  Chrome was the last to implement.

Comment: NYC is 4 hours behind UTC, so it does need to be specified according to the answer right?

Comment: @fritz - no, if the local time zone is 4 hours behind UTC for the date in question, then you do not *need* to pass the offset - (unless you are trying to disambiguate values in a DST fall-back transition)

Comment: However, specifying it is always more correct, so if you have it then yes - use it.  But you have to make sure it's the correct offset for the date in question, which can change between standard time and daylight time.  Also, my earlier comments were before you clarified that the output was coming from MongoDB shell, so they may or may not apply depending on what version of MongoDB you are using and what version of ECMAScript it is adhering to for the Date object construction.

Comment: @MattJohnson—except for browsers that get it wrong, like Safari. :-(